# Eclipse cdt, check box pressed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

i was happily coding in c++ with my eclipse-cdt when..

i tried to compile, there was some error, it asked me something like:

> "there are some compilation error. do you want to run anyways?"

and just after this a check box with something like:

> don't ask this again

and i by mistake pressed space key in my keyboard and now each time i try to compile and there is some error, it will run the last compiled binary and i try to test my application without understand and this drive me mad.

please! help me! i want to revert the checkbox! please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching

The radio button is labelled "Continue launch if project contains errors".